# Vim: How can I disable the mouse in Operator-Pending Mode?

Tags: vim, macvim

I have a problem: When I initiate Operator-Pending Mode with `d` or `c` and I click on the active window, the mouse click acts as a motion. For example, I can position my cursor at the start of a paragraph, press `d`, then click on a word at the end of the paragraph and Vim will delete from the cursor position to the end of the paragraph. I would like to disable this feature to prevent accidental mouse clicks.

I have added the following in my .vimrc, which tells Vim to enable the mouse only in Normal Mode and Visual Mode.

```
set mouse=nv
```

However, this does not work. I can enter Operator-Pending Mode and still use a mouse click as the motion. Is it possible to tell Vim not to accept mouse clicks for motions in Operator-Pending Mode?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`:help 'mouse'` won't help, here, so you can set it to `a` or any desired value.

You could disable the left mouse in operator-pending mode, though:

```
onoremap <LeftMouse> <Nop>
```

which prevents mouse clicks motions in operator-pending mode. Note that, with that mapping, a mouse click is not considered as a motion anymore but it also sort of "breaks out" of operator-pending mode, which may or may not be a problem.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you!